# Luggage Locker in Brussels

Tags: brussels, luggage-storage

I am planning a trip to Geel in Belgium in mid-December. I will arrive in Brussels early in the morning.

My plan is to have a walk around Brussels and then take the train to Geel from Bruxelles Nord/Brussel Noord train station.

The problem is that walking around with a suitcase, is not very convenient. So I was wondering if there's a safe place to keep luggage for a few hours preferably near the Bruxelles Nord/Brussel Noord train station or if there's no other solution somwhere in Brussels.

Answer (score 2):

According to the website from the National Rail company, there are automatic [luggage lockers at Brussels-North station](http://www.belgianrail.be/en/stations-and-train/search-a-station/2/bruxelles-nord.aspx).

[Brussels-South station also has a staffed left-luggage facility](http://www.belgianrail.be/en/stations-and-train/search-a-station/1/bruxelles-midi.aspx) and is generally bigger and nicer (at least I remember it that way) so it could be a good alternative.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! Do you have any idea about the cost? Also, can be large suitcases fit in the lockers?

Comment: @Thanos I don't know. Personally, I would go to Brussels-South so that if the lockers are not big enough you could still go to the left-luggage desk (do check the train schedule btw, even if the route you found is over Brussels-North, most trains call in at both stations).